# How to convert volt-second data into power-frequency domain?

Tags: time, voltage, frequency, power

guys, I am new to physics. Due to my project, I have to utilize my data in the frequency domain. However, my data is in the time domain. So I wanted to ask how I can transform my Volt-time domain data into a power-frequency spectrum? If you suggest using FFT how can it be more efficiently applied? And what is the physical meaning of this conversion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: See: [But what is the Fourier Transform?](https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY) FFT/DCT is designed to be efficient, you can't really do it any more efficiently than that. You could use the Hadamard transform if you really want to eke out performance, but that is only an *approximation* to the DCT (though good enough for modern lossy video compression).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.